# echo json_encode($array) - fade out after 2s

Tags: php

```html
echo json_encode($array);
```

The code above works fine..I need help with fading out the echo after 2s, otherwise the screen just fills up with values from the array (array has over 5000 items).

Comment: The echo is obviously in php, Can I use javascript within the php to achieve this?

Comment: can you show your code? where you using this json_encode

Comment: You can load your array partially, example from 0, 100 and with a get request, you can increase it.

Comment: $result = ($mailResult = mail($email, $subject, $message, $headerString)) ? 'good' : ' bad';
     $array = array('sent' => $result, 'email' => $email);
    
    
    
    echo json_encode($array);